# How to import excel file to fill labels which is in apex?

Tags: excel, oracle, oracle-apex

I have a page on APEX which has several labels.User should fill these labels to create new record.But this is a new application.The company has used excel to keep these records.Now It is the problem;
Users want to have a option that import excel file and excel file's cells fill required labels.I can not find any method to do that.
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I an tell, you can't do it on that page.

What you can do is to create a **Data Loading** process. How? Create a new page and choose ... well, *Data Loading* page type. The Wizard will lead you through the process (there's no sense in typing it over here).

Once you're done, Apex will create 4 pages which will cover the whole process:

- choose the source
- perform mapping
- data validation
- display the final result

and let you load data stored in those files. Though, you can't import the native Excel file (.XLS or .XLSX) - save that file as a .CSV (comma-separated values) and then use it as data source for the loading process.